# Cloning from private git on vagrant provision?

Tags: git, vagrant

I am wanting to retrieve a project from a private project in bitbucket while provisioning a Linux based Vagrant box, but I am running this is failing.

The operation is of the form:

```
cd /tmp

git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myuser/myproject.git
```

In my Vagrant file I have specified:

```
 config.ssh.forward_agent = true
```

The output of the operation is:

```
==> default: Cloning into 'myproject'...
==> default: Host key verification failed.
==> default: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
==> default: 
==> default: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
==> default: and the repository exists.
```

If I `vagrant ssh` into the box and then attempt the same git clone I have no issues cloning the repository.

I have tried adding the following (where "ubuntu" is the default user for box "ubuntu/xenial64"):

```
sudo -H -u ubuntu ssh-keygen -R bitbucket.org
sudo -H -u ubuntu git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myuser/myproject.git
```

This just results in:

```
==> default: Host bitbucket.org not found in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts
==> default: Cloning into 'myproject'...
==> default: Host key verification failed.
==> default: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
==> default: 
==> default: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
==> default: and the repository exists.
```

I also tried adding the following to the script, but no change:

```
ssh-keyscan -H bitbucket.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
sudo -H -u ubuntu ssh-keyscan -H bitbucket.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Vagrant configuration:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

  config.vm.synced_folder './', '/vagrant', disabled: false, create: true

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb, override|
    vb.name = 'myproject-dev-standalone'    

    # Web server HTTP front end
    override.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 10080
    # Web server HTTPS front end    
    override.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 443, host: 10443

    override.vm.provision :shell do |s|
      s.path = "provision/install.sh"
      s.privileged = false
    end
  end

end
```

Can anyone suggest of way to be able to `git clone` during provision, without hard-coding the password into the install script?

Comment: most probably you're running the provision script from root, add `privileged: "false"` and vagrant user will execute so it should be good to go. Please confirm the assumption or detail how you run the provision

Comment: did not change anything. have added Vagrantfile contents to question

Comment: Turns out I was specifying the wrong domain for 'ssh-keyscan -H'. I had specified bitbucket.com, instead of bitbucket.org. I totally missed that. Changing that line helps. The "privileged" wasn't necessary, but it is good to know about it. - Thanks